# Trying to set up Fuel API on Drupal and getting Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'ExactTargetWSDL.xml'

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

I am trying to get the Fuel API working on a drupal module that I made, I am using Drupal 7 and I downloaded the FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9 to my module that I want to use it on.  I followed the configuration guide and I have curl, mcrypt, openssl, and soap all installed and enabled, I have created a config.php file and added my ClientID and ClientSecret, and I am getting the error: "Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'ExactTargetWSDL.xml' : failed to load external entity "ExactTargetWSDL.xml" in /t_user_registration/FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9/ET_Client.php on line 65"
I have tried downloading the wsdl file from https://webservice.exacttarget.com/ETFramework.wsdl and renaming it ExactTargetWSDL.xml.  I have tried $client = new ET_Client(); blank with false and with true.  Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the framework, renamed it ExactTargetWSDL.xml and placed a copy local to the ET_Client.php and in the same folder as the script and that resolved the issue.

Comment: I tried that before, and it was still giving the same error.  But after messing with it for a bit it just started working.